# Problema con click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

buenas llevo una semana aprendiendo un poco de javascript y jquery pero llegue a un problema que no he podido encontrar solución. Lo que intento hacer es a partir de una tabla lograr editar sus elementos de esta manera: se muestra una tabla con varios elementos, por cada fila hay un boton, si se presiona el boton esa fila se transforma en valores input (para lograr escribir en ellos), si se presiona nuevamente el boton (uno nuevo creado con id diferente) se envian los datos a la base de datos y luego se debe transformar la fila que eran input en un elemento fila de una tabla nuevamente con los datos actualizados. El problema es que la función click al hacer click sobre el boton nuevo(con id boton) no hace nada, nisiquiera muestr un alert o un log como le indique. ¿Por que pasa esto? De antemano muchas gracias

Funcion que recibe el valor de los campos al presionar el botón por segunda vez(nuevo boton para confirmar edición)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("jQuery está funcionando"); 
    jQuery("#boton").click(function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        alert("se oprimio el boton"); 
    console.log("funciona"); 
        var especiee = jQuery("#especie").val();
        var generoo = jQuery("#genero").val();
        var familiaa = jQuery("#familia").val();
        var calidadd = jQuery("#calidad").val();
        var tamañoo = jQuery("#tamaño").val();
        var ciudadd = jQuery("#ciudad").val();
        var comentarioo = jQuery("#comentario").val();
        var precioo = jQuery("#precio").val();
});


                });
```

Esta funcion me transforma en editable el form:

```
    function transformarEnEditable(nodo){
    //El nodo recibido es SPAN
    if (editando == false) {
    editando = "true";

    var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD
    var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

    var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var especie = nodosEnTr[0].textContent; 
    var genero = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
    var familia = nodosEnTr[2].textContent; 
    var calidad = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
    var tamaño = nodosEnTr[4].textContent; 
    var ciudad = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;
    var comentario = nodosEnTr[6].textContent;
    var precio = nodosEnTr[7].textContent;
    var Editar = nodosEnTr[8].textContent;
    var nuevoCodigoHtml = '<td><input type="text" name="especie" id="especie" value="'+especie+'" size="17"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="genero" id="genero" value="'+genero+'" size="10"</td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="familia" id="familia" value="'+familia+'" size="10"</td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="calidad" id="calidad" value="'+calidad+'" size="5"</td> '+
    '<td><input type="text" name="tamaño" id="tamaño" value="'+tamaño+'" size="5"</td> '+
    '<td><input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="'+ciudad+'" size="10"</td> '+
    '<td><input type="text" name="comentario" id="comentario" value="'+comentario+'" size="20"</td> '+
    '<td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="'+precio+'" size="5"</td> '+
    '<td><input class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton" Value="aceptar" type="submit"></input></td>'+
    '<td><input class="btn btn-danger" value="eliminar" type="submit"></input> ' ;






nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;}}
```

y con esto muestro los datos:

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shells');

    $request=mysqli_query($conexion,"select especie, genero,familia,calidad,tamano,ciudad,comentario,precio from shell where habitad='land'");

    while($prueba=$request->fetch_assoc()){
?> 
    <tr class="info">

<td><?php echo $prueba['especie'] ;     ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['genero']   ;    ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['familia']   ;   ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['calidad']   ;   ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['tamano']   ;    ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['ciudad']   ;    ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['comentario'];   ?>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $prueba['precio']   ;    ?>  </td> 

<td><input type=submit name="editar" value="Editar" onclick="transformarEnEditable(this)" class="btn btn-primary"> </input> </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger"></input></td>
    </tr>

<?php   } ?>
```

Comment: Primero dices que creas una tabla supongo que con varios registros,
verifica que el boton de cada fila no tenga el mismo id osea "boton
jQuery("#boton")" segun veo, por que si le colocas el mismo id a todos los botones no funcionara correctamente

Comment: Pero deberia funcionar para el primer elemento por lo menos o no? y ni para ese funciona, pense que se sobreescribia la id (veo que no jaja) es que cada vez que hacia click en el primer boton se creaba uno nuevo con una id "boton" entonces la idea era que cada vez que presionaba en una fila distinta se creaba un boton nuevo con id boton que reemplazara al otro

Comment: Es mejor que crees botones con id diferentes para cada fila creada y utilizar javascript para llamar a una función al presionar el boton

Comment: oka, hare eso gracias ^^

Comment: @JavierRussellRichardsValenz la solución a tu problema es más sencilla de lo que piensas pero para eso debes enfocar el problema desde otro punto de vista, por ejemplo, que tal si en vez de modificar el DOM ya este trae los input pero desactivados, y luego cuando presionan el boton de editar, pues activas los input, este enfoque te haria mas facil el desarrollo, al menos piensalo.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que cuando usar el onReady el botón no existe, entonces JQuery no le asigna dicha función de click, si tu pegas ese pedazo de código

```
jQuery("#boton").click(function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    alert("se oprimio el boton"); 
console.log("funciona"); 
    var especiee = jQuery("#especie").val();
    var generoo = jQuery("#genero").val();
    var familiaa = jQuery("#familia").val();
    var calidadd = jQuery("#calidad").val();
    var tamañoo = jQuery("#tamaño").val();
    var ciudadd = jQuery("#ciudad").val();
    var comentarioo = jQuery("#comentario").val();
    var precioo = jQuery("#precio").val();
```

});

Debajo de tu función verás que funciona

```
 function transformarEnEditable(nodo){
//El nodo recibido es SPAN
if (editando == false) {
editando = "true";

var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD
var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
var especie = nodosEnTr[0].textContent; 
var genero = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
var familia = nodosEnTr[2].textContent; 
var calidad = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
var tamaño = nodosEnTr[4].textContent; 
var ciudad = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;
var comentario = nodosEnTr[6].textContent;
var precio = nodosEnTr[7].textContent;
var Editar = nodosEnTr[8].textContent;
var nuevoCodigoHtml = '<td><input type="text" name="especie" id="especie" value="'+especie+'" size="17"></td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="genero" id="genero" value="'+genero+'" size="10"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="familia" id="familia" value="'+familia+'" size="10"</td>'+
'<td><input type="text" name="calidad" id="calidad" value="'+calidad+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="tamaño" id="tamaño" value="'+tamaño+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="'+ciudad+'" size="10"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="comentario" id="comentario" value="'+comentario+'" size="20"</td> '+
'<td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value="'+precio+'" size="5"</td> '+
'<td><input class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton" Value="aceptar" type="submit"></input></td>'+
'<td><input class="btn btn-danger" value="eliminar" type="submit"></input> ' ;
nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;}

 jQuery("#boton").click(function(evento){
        evento.preventDefault();
        alert("se oprimio el boton"); 
    console.log("funciona"); 
        var especiee = jQuery("#especie").val();
        var generoo = jQuery("#genero").val();
        var familiaa = jQuery("#familia").val();
        var calidadd = jQuery("#calidad").val();
        var tamañoo = jQuery("#tamaño").val();
        var ciudadd = jQuery("#ciudad").val();
        var comentarioo = jQuery("#comentario").val();
        var precioo = jQuery("#precio").val();
});
}
```

También puedes intentar cambiar el

```
jQuery("#boton").click(function(evento){
```

Por

```
$( "boton" ).on( "click", {
```

Desde el onReady a ver si así funciona sin necesidad de incrustarlo directo en la función

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder :D 

Intente lo que dijiste pero no me funciono de ninguna manera :/ no se si el problema esta en que estoy usando mal la funcion o quizas me estoy refiriendo al boton antes de ser creado pero no veo como pueda estar pasando eso

Comment: Lo intentaste copiando el método tal y como lo puse en el método? si es así y no funciona puedes intentar asignándole un id diferente a cada boton

Comment: Lo probe justo como me dijiste, lo que hice ahora fue añadir un onclick al boton que creaba (en vez de usar la funcion click de jquery) y asi me funciono el boton :D aun no puedo hacer lo que quiero jaja pero es porque no entiendo mucho ajax aun (busco busco y no entiendo como funciona exactamente ) pero seguire averiguando, muchas muchas gracias te pasaste :D

Answer (score 0):

El problema que creo que te esta pasando es que estas invocando un evento que esta atado a varios elementos (botones) con un mismo id, en este caso #boton, trata de invocarlo por la clase para ver que pasa, te digo esto porque cuando atas un evento por el id solo es atado a un solo elemento (un solo boton) y para los demás así tengan el mismo id no lo va a reconocer, mi recomendación es invocarlo por la clase y no por el id ya que con la clase si puede ser atado a varios elementos. Nos cuentas si te sirvio.

Original:

`jQuery("#boton").click(function(evento){...`

Sugerencia:

`jQuery(".boton").click(function(evento){...`

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida pon un ejemplo con código

Comment: Ok lo tomaré en cuenta gracias

Answer (score 0):

Amigo usa jquery de esta forma para acceder a los selectores `$("#tuID")` se ve mas legible .

Ademas te paso un dato importante si quieres llamar funciones dentro de tu codigo js ,debes reemplazar `$(document).ready(function(){ tu codigo })` por `$(function() { tu codigo })`, porque si no , te mostrara que la funcion no ha sido declarada , espero y te sirva .

Answer (score -1):

```
<table id="table">
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary"  id="boton" Value="aceptar" 
type="submit"></input></td>
</table>
$("#table").on("click","#boton",function(){

})
```

El elemento al cual quiere delegar el evento es dinamico, el evento se debe de delegar sobre un elemento ya existente como la tabla, despues de indicar el evento colocando una coma se coloca el elemento dinamico, en este caso el boton.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu aporte, ¿podrías agregar una descripción de lo que hace tu código y como este resuelve el problema planteado por el autor? recuerda siempre basarte en [answer]